# How to handle Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK and Onesignal SDK in a same Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

We have integrated both Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK and Onesignal SDK in a same Project.

Since we need to send Push Notification using both Services. If I sent notification from Onesignal, I get two notifications, one from Onesignal and the other from Firebase when OnMessageReceive is triggered.

Is this a bug with Onesignal or this is the case if we integrated both SDK?

Please suggest how we can avoid notification gets duplicated.

Comment: Are two notifications being displayed or are both callbacks just firing?

Comment: just firing only, but now i controlled the notifications by using custom key

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. I guess one way would be to check for the messageId of the message from `onMessageReceived` callback, which is null when sending a notification using OneSignal? How did you resolve this?

Comment: @tehmaestro answer updated check it below

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I controlled the notifications by using custom key

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
        //Log.e("onMessageReceived", data.toString());
        if (!data.has("custom"))
        {
            //Log.d("onMessageReceived", "not having custom key");//its from firebase 
        }else{
            //Log.d("fonMessageReceived", "having custom key");//its from onesignal 
        }
}
```